# Attribute selector containing a colon is not finding any elements

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have following HTML-Tags and want to select them by jQuery:

```
<div foo:bar="test"></div>
<span foo:bar="test2"></span>
<xxx foo:bar="test3"></xxx>
```

So, I want to select all tags, that have the attribute `foo:bar`.

I tried following:

```
$('[foo:bar]').addClass("fooBar");
// Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [adv:sensorid]
```

I know, that the correct Syntax would be something like `data-foo-bar`, but I have to use `foo:bar`.

Is this even possible in jQuery?

I can even use AngularJS if it helps somehow. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's possible. You need to escape any special character with a `\\`

```
$('[foo\\:bar]').addClass("fooBar");
```

[**DOC:**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Comment: Thank you very much. <3 It works perfect! Ill accept your answer in 10m (its not possible yet).

Comment: @Tream glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

For example we have HTML:

```
<span id="item-1023293" pr:position="hr">Jhon</span>
```

We need to select all span elements by attribute.

So the selector should be like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span[pr\\:position="hr"]')
```