# Writing a selector for CSS or jQuery when the attribute name contains a colon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, css-selectors

I've been trying to figure out how to get [KanjiVG](http://kanjivg.tagaini.net/index.html) to work for a bit now, and while I'm able to get the images to display, I'm having trouble manipulating them (specifically, highlighting the radical, which is identified using a custom `kvg:radical` attribute).

Here's how I'm including the SVG file:

```html
        <div id="svg-container"></div>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                // Load SVG file and insert it into the container
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "img/kanjivg/<?php echo str_pad($kanji->ucs, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);?>.svg",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(data) {
                        jQuery("#svg-container").html(data.documentElement);

                        // Modify SVG properties
                        jQuery("[kvg\\:radical]").css("stroke", "red");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

It loads fine, but everything remains black.  I tried putting the `jQuery("[kvg\\:radical]").css("stroke", "red");` line into the console to see if it would work, and it keeps selecting nothing, even though I've opened the file and confirmed the presence of said attribute.

I tried working around this with CSS as follows (using `display: none;` to make it patently obvious if the selector worked):

```css
[kvg\:radical] {
    display: none;
}
```

But it's still showing up.  Yet if I just tell it to do something to `svg`, `svg g`, or `svg text`, it works fine—it's when I try to access selectors with colons in them that it develops a blind spot.

Using a function from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/215950) to dump a list of attributes on the node in question, we produced the following:

```js
jQuery('#kvg\\:04ee4-g1').each(function(){
    jQuery.each(this.attributes, function(){
        if(this.specified){
            console.log(this.name, this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

The output of which was as follows:

```
[Log] id – "kvg:04ee4-g1"
[Log] kvg:element – "人"
[Log] kvg:position – "top"
[Log] kvg:radical – "general"
```

...so it *knows* the attribute exists, but it doesn't seem to want to allow direct access to it.

I guess one workaround is to use the foreach to go through the nodes and perform its function if it finds an attribute ending in "radical", but that feels like a horribly inefficient method of doing business here.  Is there a way I can grab elements containing `[kvg:radical]` in JavaScript or CSS that will work properly?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482340/attribute-selector-containing-a-colon-is-not-finding-any-elements it should work.

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/37ahfq6r/1/ Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: OK, this is getting a bit maddening—it's working when I put the code I'm using into a fiddle as well, yet when I run the exact same code on the dev version of the site I'm building in XAMPP the CSS selector doesn't work and attempts to access it via JS in the console come back with empty result sets.  Only noticeable difference I can find is that I'm using jQuery 3.6.0, whereas JSfiddle only goes up to 3.4.1.  Is there something else about the environment I can check?

Comment: As mentioned, it's not reproducing the error, for some reason, but here's the fiddle I mentioned in my previous comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaji_Sensei/tk0rwzpu/3/

Comment: I doubt the jQuery version would matter -- for selectors like this jQuery simply calls the browser's `querySelectorAll()` function.